# leaflet markercluster plugin error "this._featureGroup.hasLayer is not a function"

Tags: leaflet, markerclusterer

When i'm trying to remove layer from markerClusterGroup i've got an error "this._featureGroup.hasLayer is not a function" at removeLayer method.

```
clusters = L.markerClusterGroup()
clusters.hasLayer(layer));//returns true
clusters.removeLayer(layer);//cause an error "this._featureGroup.hasLayer is not a function"
```

What may cause such error?

Comment: Usage of clearLayers instead of removeLayer works fine